# Proof that an algorithm like this does not exist

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I am struggling to find a proof for the following statement. Prove that there is no comparison-based algorithm that receives an n sized array and emits an array of the same elements, in which all the elements found in indexes divided by 3 now appear in their sorted form in these indexes in linear time.

For example the array : 8 6 1 3 0 9 4

After executing the algorithm the array will look like : 3 6 1 4 0 9 8

originally the elements 8,3,4 appear in the array in indexes that are a multiply of 3 and after executing the algorithm they still will appear in indexes that are a multiply of 3 but this time they will appear in their sorted form in this case 3,4,8.

I need to prove that such algorithm does not exist. I tried assuming that statement was right so that at some point I will get contradiction but it did not work out with me. Thanks for any help.

Comment: If I've understood your description correctly, then this algorithm **does** exist: take the subset of elements with indices divisible by 3, sort them, then insert them back into the array at indices divisible by 3 in their new order. Did you forget to include an extra condition like "*...and runs in time linear in the length of the input*"?

Comment: no there is no extra condition

Comment: @shadihelf as hnefatl said, if there is no extra condition the algorithm obviously exists.

Comment: oops my mistake I did not notice an extra demand that the algorithm must run at linear time

Comment: Imagine something that does this in linear time exists. If so, think of how you can run this method to sort the 0 mod 3 positions, then the 1 mod 3, then the 2 mod 3. All this in linear time. Now you have 3 sorted subarrays and you can merge them also in linear time. So you ended up sorting an array with a comparison based method in linear time, which is absurd

Comment: juvian the algorithm must work only on the elements in the 0 mod 3 positions and it can not work on the elements in the 1 mod 3 positions and 2 mod 3 positions

Comment: The point that @juvian was trying to make is that if the algorithm existed, then you could use it to sort the 1 mod 3 and 2 mod 3 positions in linear time, then merge the results. The result would be a comparison-based sorting algorithm that runs in O(n) time: something that's proven to be impossible. So, no, no such algorithm exists.

Comment: @shadihelf it will work on 1 mod 3 and 2 mod 3 if you add elements to the array, or swap positions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two arguments that prove such an algorithm cannot exist. First, as pointed out in comments, if such an algorithm did exist, then you could do the following:

1. Run the algorithm on the 0 mod 3 elements
2. Run the algorithm on the 1 mod 3 elements
3. Run the algorithm on the 2 mod 3 elements
4. Merge the three lists to create a fully sorted array.

Each of the first three steps would run in O(n/3) time, and the last step would run in O(n) time. That would give you an O(n) comparison sorting algorithm. But comparison sorting is proven to be O(n log n).

Second argument is that given an array of n items, you want to sort n/3 items in O(n) time. As mentioned, comparison sorting is O(n log n). So sorting n/3 items will be O((n/3) * log(n/3)). So to sort those n/3 items in O(n) time, `log(n/3)` must be less than 3. The base 2 log of 8 is equal to 3. So if n > 24, then sorting n/3 items will take more than O(n) comparisons.